# Undefined dynamic lookup in cx_oracle installation on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, oracle11g, x86-64, cx-oracle

I am trying to install cx_oracle for use with python. I have followed these two guides ([1](http://joelvasallo.com/?p=276)) ([2](http://kevindalias.com/2014/03/26/how-to-set-up-cx_oracle-for-python-on-mac-os-x-10-89/)) and have done some trial and error with the different steps that each take as well as uninstalling all and trying each guide on their own. Regardless I am still stuck with a bunch of warnings at the build and then get this error upon actually trying to install:

> cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -L/Users//oracle/instantclient_11_2 -lclntsh -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.so -shared-libgcc
>
> ld: library not found for -lclntsh
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

The python error that accompanies it that is generated by pip is

> Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/vn/12yxd3j51zq6srt57txjnkssfm4bvn/T/pip-build-71LWsF/cx-Oracle/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/vn/12yxd3j51zq6srt57txjnkssfm4bvn/T/pip-M7g1qH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vn/12yxd3j51zq6srt57txjnkssfm4bvn/T/pip-build-71LWsF/cx-Oracle

I am thinking this might have to do with the architecture tags but I have no experience in how to fix that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this helped,
export ARCH=x86_64